# Rails will_paginage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using will_paginate for pagination,

When i reach the last page and then click on Next link its again taking me to first page,

Actually i want to disable the Next button when i reach the last page.

please advise me how to solve this..

this is the code i used for pagination

> <%= will_paginate @users, 
>                   :prev_label => "Preevious", 
>                   :next_label => "Next",
>                   :page_links =>true,
>                   :renderer => PaginationListLinkRenderer
>       %>

Comment: Please post your ":renderer => PaginationListLinkRenderer" code. This is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
@users = User.paginate :per_page => 5, 
    :page => params[:page], 
    :order => 'name ASC',
    :conditions => ""
```

View:

```
<%= will_paginate @users, 
    :previous_label => "Previous", 
    :next_label => "Next", 
    :inner_window => "2", 
    :outer_window => "0" %>
```

Above is all my code and it works for me in will_paginate. Once reached down the last page, the "Next" link change to bolded text, so as the last page number (see image below).

[image]

Comment: no, i still can access Next link even after reaching last page

Comment: i cannot reproduce your problem. I post my code and made various, and still it works prefect for me. Did you install will_paginate as a gem or as plug in and which version is it?

Answer (score 1):

I am using

```
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

and it is working fine. It disables the next link when i reach the last page.